# Cap mongodb collection (but not using CappedCollections)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to create a collection which can only have specific number of documents (say 1000 records). However, I cannot use the capped collection because it just deletes the older records(and I want my prog to handle what to delete). Does anyone have any suggestions for a fine way to implement this? I have not found a whole lot of encouraging ideas online.

Comment: Sounds arcane... why? Can't the application code handle this?

Comment: If you want your application to handle deletes, then your application needs to manage the capacity of the collection as well. What would you expect to happen if a client inserted the 1001th document to MongoDB but MongoDB can't delete a document because your application code is supposed to handle that?